# Connecting Azure DevOps with Azure Bot services

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-bot-service

I was able to create authenticate users against AD v2 (Graph) but Azure DevOps isn't part of Graph API so I need to authenticate the users against Azure DevOps directly.

On the DevOps [new app](https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register) registration:
When I tried to set the `Authorization callback URL` to `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect` I get an error saying the url is already used (bug?), I've set it to `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web///redirect` and it was accepted.

Now I have:

- App ID
- App secret
- Client Secret
- Authorize URL
- Access Token URL
- Authorized Scopes

On the Azure Bot connection setting I choose `Generic Oauth 2` and set the following: (used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) page)

- Client Id: < DevOps app's `app id` >
- Client secret: < DevOps app's `client secret` >
- Authorization < URL: DevOps app's `Authorize URL` >
- Token URL: < DevOps app's `Access Token URL` >
- Refresh URL: < DevOps app's `Authorize URL` > (wrong?)
- Scopes: < DevOps app's `Authorized Scopes` >

Now as I hit the 'Test Connection' I get `400 BAD REQUEST` with:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Web.Profile.Controllers.DelegatedAuthorizationException' was thrown.
```

Any ideas?

Update:
Looks like it's indeed the callback issue.
Azure DevOps won't accept existing callback URL (I've opened a bug and it was closed by them).
Bot Framework guys are still looking into this, if they'll generate per-bot URL (as they should) it will probably solve the issue

Comment: Can you add some perspective on what you are trying to accomplish? Is this to allow CI/CD to deploy the bot code to Azure? Or are you trying to do Azure Dev Ops operations from within the bot?

Comment: @DanaV The later is correct. I'm trying to create a bot which can perform Azure DevOps operations. DevOps closed my issue claiming this is not a bug and I should open a new 'suggestion'. Bot Framework are still looking into this

Answer (score 0):

Try using Autorization URL as

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com
```

and in your **azure bot services** go to **OAuth Connection Settings**, fill all the details and test.